# bat file command for Write exact plsql query output into csv file

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file

I want to execute query from batch file and put exact output of query into csv file.
Like:
my query is : select sysdate from dual.
Output of this :

```
Sysdate
23-feb-2013
```

So, in csv it stored as

```
sysdate
22-feb-2013
```

DB: Oracle 11g
OS: windows 7

Kindly plz help me to achieve this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c:\myfolder\mybatch.bat:

```
call sqlplus oracleuser/oraclepwd@oracledb @c:\myfolder\myquery.sql
```

c:\myfolder\myquery.sql:

```
set head off
set feed off
set pagesize 0
spool c:\myfolder\myresult.csv
prompt sysdate
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual;
spool off
set head on
set feed 6
quit
```